# NoMethodError (undefined method `current_user=' heroku and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Can't work out what I've done to mess this up.  It works on localhost but not when I deploy any more.  I have migrated the database and restarted heroku but it's still not working.

My heroku log is

```
  NoMethodError (undefined method `current_user=' for #<Class:0x000000044ac488>)
```

current_user is referenced many times the app and has previously worked fine.  And this is the same error when trying to load many different pages.  It's not pointing me to a particular action...

Comment: What does your ApplicationController look like?

Comment: class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 favourites_path
end
   

end

Comment: Also according to your log, the error is occurring when you access the root path `/`. But the action you provided is `update`. Are you routing `/` to `#update`?

Comment: I've just changed the main post.  I don't think it is update in particular as it's happening on other pages too and I can't find what action it is referencing

Comment: Do you get the error locally if you start the server in production environment? `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`

Comment: thanks for trying to help - I've just reverting to an old commit and will try and make my changes again but more slowly so I can work out what's going wrong

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I accidentally removed the devise route:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "registrations"}
end
```